# keyboard is not shown after pause or stop fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, broadcastreceiver

Android doesn't show keyboard in focused edit text even when click on it, after pause or stop fragment . For example I'm focused on edit text keyboard is shown, everything is okay, then I clicked on home button ( or just leave the fragment ) after resumed the same fragment , focus is still in edit text , but not able to show keyboard again . from logs :

> W/InputMethodManager: The current service view is not the focus view

I have just one activity with following info in manifest :

> activity
>                   android:name=".presentation.main.MainActivity"
>                   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
>                   android:screenOrientation="portrait">

in some cases we need to close keyboard manually and using following broadcast :

```
  val view = this@MainActivity.currentFocus
            if (view != null) {
                val imm =
                    this@MainActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
            }
```

Comment: inside `onResume` method check if the current focus is on the desired EditText then make `editText.performClick()` method

Comment: I don click manually on edittext field but doesn't make sense , just got the message from logs ( mentioned in question)

Answer (score 0):

To force open the keyboard on EditText use below code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

If it is still doesn't works then

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: if (focusedView != null) {
            focusedView?.postDelayed({
                val editText = if (focusedView is CustomSearchField) {
                    focusedView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.searchField)
                } else if (focusedView is AppCompatEditText) {
                    focusedView
                } else {
                    null
                }
                val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
            }, 200)
        }

Comment: I added this code in onStart method, but is doesn't make sense :((((( 
 override fun onPause() {
        focusedView = this.currentFocus
        super.onPause()
    }

Comment: @Nininea why are you writing inside `onStart` method. post this code inside `onResume` method